# Replacing some numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code that goes into the console of my browser. This code is designed to be used on a maths website that asks questions to you.

Now my script is supposed to be pasted into the browser console, and this script basically removes the `=` from the "question", puts the "question" into `eval()` and then inputs the answer into the inputbox.

Here is that code: [image: Script]

Now I get this question here: [image: Tricky question]. Here `eval()` thinks that it is `16+20` and the answer keeps outputing as `36`.

Is there any way to change this to `20-16`? I cannot use `.replace` to change the `+` into a `-`, as that will change it for the other `+` questions as well.

```
function showAnswer() {
  var inputBox = document.getElementsByClassName("questions-input-adjustment questions-input-width-v3")[0];
  var submitButton = document.getElementsByClassName('question-input-form')[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var question = document.getElementsByClassName("questions-text-alignment")[0].innerText;
    question = question.replace(' =', '');
    question = question.replace('×', '*')
    question = question.replace('=', '');
    var answer = eval(question);
    inputBox.value = answer;
  }

  var awnser = addbits(equasion)
  var inputBox = document.getElementsByClassName("questions-input-adjustment questions-input-width-v3")[0];
  var submitButton = document.getElementsByClassName('question-input-form')[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var question = document.getElementsByClassName("questions-text-alignment")[0].innerText;
    question = question.replace(' =', '');
    question = question.replace('×', '*')
    question = question.replace('=', '');

    var answer = eval(question);
    inputBox.value = answer;
  }

  var awnser = addbits(equasion)

  document.getElementById('dashow').innerText = awnser;
  document.getElementsByClassName("questions-input-adjustment questions-input-width-v3")["0"].value = awnser;
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == "81") {
    showAnswer();
  }
}
```

Comment: paste you code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your source code and example, the original question string before the replacement would be: "16+ =20".

Your current code only handles this case:

(1) "16+20= "

You can use a regex expression to handle the scenarios when the blank is not the sum of the two numbers: 

(2) " +16=20"

(3) "16+ =20"

```
var question = "16+ =20";
var regex = /(\s\+)|(\+\s)/i

if (regex.test(question)){
    question = str.replace(" =", "");
  question = str.replace("=","");
  question = str.replace("+","-");
  answer = -eval(question); 
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nf2fqyv5/8/

Comment: How/where would I put this into my code? : I have edited the code into the post

Comment: Just after the line when you get your question string.